# Example of vector space such that $cv = 0$ where $c \ne 0$ and $v \ne \vec{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there an example of a vector space $V/F$ such that $0 \ne c \in F$, $\vec{0} \ne v \in V$, but $c \cdot v = 0 $?

I couldn't think of an example.

Comment: No. If $c\neq 0$, then $c^{-1}$ exists. Thus if $cv=0$, then $c^{-1}cv=v=0$ which contradicts the assumption that $v\neq 0$.

Comment: This makes me think of a useful (non)example to keep in mind with vector spaces: the circle $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is not a vector space (over $\mathbb R$). (It came to mind because if it were, then it would be an example of a vector space with your desired property.) It's a nice exercise to figure out which vector space axiom(s) fail for $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$!

Comment: @Matt Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2):

No. Suppose $v\neq 0$. If $c\neq 0$, then $c^{-1}$ exists. Thus if $cv=0$, then

\begin{eqnarray*}
v & = & (c^{-1}c)v \\
  & = & c^{-1}(cv) \\
  & = & c^{-1}\cdot 0 \\
  & = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}

which contradicts the assumption that $v\neq 0$.